# UK visitor Visa

Tags: uk, paperwork, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas, applications

I had given a personal short-term credit of 2000 GBP to a family friend, he credited back to my account 6 days before my visa application, my bank statement demonstrates both the outgoing and incoming transfer of funds, I have a attached my salary slips to prove the money I had in my account was earned by me, I have to go there for my exam which is only conducted in UK and not anywhere else. In addition to that I have my a sponsor and an invitation letter from a person who works there. Will it constitute as fund parking?

Comment: How much is your usual salary? How much is the bank balance?

Comment: Just mention about that credit/debit in the covering letter so that it doesn't cause confusion for the visa officer.

Comment: It is not funds parking (that would be someone depositing funds in your account to deliberately try to improve the optics of your financial circumstances), but as an *unusual* transaction you should explain the background to it in your application

Answer (score 1):

Since the amount came out and came back from the same account, its usually not an issue, as the reason is obvious. However, the official who checks the document can miss that and have a possibility of flagging the account as funds parking.

So, you should have a covering letter mentioning this unusual transaction and explain the reason behind this. This will make sure that no invalid assumptions are made by the officer.